# String data manipulated given CSV variables

Tags: javascript, parsing, node.js, ecmascript-6, iteration

**The Requirements:**

List the expensable items sorted by date and location given two variables: 'categories' and 'expenses'. The Categories variable provides the following information in order: Category ID, Category Name, and whether the category is expensable (Y/N). The Expenses variable  provides the following information in order: Location, Date, Item Description, Cost, and Category Code. Each line should be displayed in the format "DATE: LOCATION - $TOTAL".

I put it together in a single JavaScript executable.

**The code:**

```
// Input Values
var categories = "CFE,Coffee,Y\nFD,Food,Y\nPRS,Personal,N";
var expenses = "Starbucks,3/10/2018,Iced Americano,4.28,CFE\nStarbucks,3/10/2018,Nitro Cold Brew,3.17,CFE\nStarbucks,3/10/2018,Souvineer Mug,8.19,PRS\nStarbucks,3/11/2018,Nitro Cold Brew,3.17,CFE\nHigh Point Market,3/11/2018,Iced Americano,2.75,CFE\nHigh Point Market,3/11/2018,Pastry,2.00,FD\nHigh Point Market,3/11/2018,Gift Card,10.00,PRS";

var AcceptableExpenses = GetAcceptableExpenses(GetAcceptableCategories(categories), expenses)

AcceptableExpenses.forEach (AcceptableExpense =>{
    console.log(AcceptableExpense.join(''))
})

function GetAcceptableExpenses(AcceptableCategories, expenses){
    var ExpensesList = expenses.split("\n")
    var AcceptableExpenseTotals = []
    var categoryIndex = 4
    var venderIndex = 0
    var dateIndex = 1
    var priceIndex = 3

    var venderDate = []
    ExpensesList.forEach(expense => {
        var expenseItemized = expense.split(',')

        if ((categoryIndex < expenseItemized.length) && IsExpenseItemAcceptable(AcceptableCategories, expenseItemized[categoryIndex])){
            venderDate = [expenseItemized[dateIndex], ": ", expenseItemized[venderIndex], " - $"].join('')

            if ( IsVenderDateIncluded(AcceptableExpenseTotals, venderDate) ){
                UpdatePrice(AcceptableExpenseTotals, venderDate, expenseItemized[priceIndex] )
            }
            else{
                AcceptableExpenseTotals.push([venderDate, expenseItemized[priceIndex] ])
            }
        }
    })
    return AcceptableExpenseTotals
}
function IsVenderDateIncluded(AcceptableExpenseTotals, venderDate){
    var venderDateIndex = 0
    var IsIncluded = false

    AcceptableExpenseTotals.forEach( AcceptableExpenseTotal =>{
        if (AcceptableExpenseTotal[venderDateIndex] === venderDate){
            IsIncluded = true
        }
    })

    return IsIncluded
}

function UpdatePrice(AcceptableExpenseTotals, venderDate, price ){
    var venderDateIndex = 0
    var priceIndex = 1
    AcceptableExpenseTotals.forEach( AcceptableExpenseTotal =>{
        if (AcceptableExpenseTotal[venderDateIndex] === venderDate){
            AcceptableExpenseTotal[priceIndex] = parseFloat( price) + parseFloat(AcceptableExpenseTotal[priceIndex])
            return
        }
    })
}

function IsExpenseItemAcceptable(AcceptableCategories, category ){
    var IsAcceptable = false
    AcceptableCategories.forEach(AcceptableCategory => {
        if (AcceptableCategory === category){
            IsAcceptable = true
        }
    })
    return IsAcceptable
}

function GetAcceptableCategories(categories){
    var categoryList = categories.split("\n")
    var AcceptableCategory = []

    for (i = 0; i < categoryList.length; i++){
        var categoryData = categoryList[i].split(',');
        var locationOf_IsExpensible = 2;
        var locationOf_Category = 0;
        if (locationOf_IsExpensible < categoryData.length ){
            if (categoryData[locationOf_IsExpensible]==="Y"){
                AcceptableCategory.push(categoryData[locationOf_Category])
            }
        }
    }
    return AcceptableCategory
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a decent start, as it uses ES6 features like arrow functions. However it could take advantage of many Javascript features - e.g. `IsExpenseItemAcceptable` could be reduced to a single line using [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Additionally, the index variables can be eliminated using the ES6 feature [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) - specifically [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring).

Instead of lines like

> ```
> var expenseItemized = expense.split(',')
>
> if ((categoryIndex < expenseItemized.length) && IsExpenseItemAcceptable(AcceptableCategories, expenseItemized[categoryIndex])){
> ```

Destructuring assignment can greatly simplify this to something like:

```
const [vendor, date, item, price, category] = expense.split(',');   
if (category && IsExpenseItemAcceptable(AcceptableCategories, category)){
```

Not only is that condition shorter, it doesn't require the use of the index and is more readable (and a typo on the word "*vendor*" was fixed).

In the example above `const` was used instead of `var`. It is recommended that `const` be the default keyword for initializing variables. If assignment is required, then use `let`.

The function `GetAcceptableCategories` could be simplified using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), similar to `Array.forEach()`.

The data structure could be changed from an array to a plain object - i.e. `{}` to provide a mapping of vendor and date combinations to prices. This would allow the elimination of the functions `updatePrice` and `IsVenderDateIncluded` because the loop could be simplified to:

```
if (category && IsExpenseItemAcceptable(AcceptableCategories, category)){
    const vendorDate = [date, ": ", vendor, " - $"].join('')
    if (vendorDate in AcceptableExpenseTotals) {
        AcceptableExpenseTotals[vendorDate] += parseFloat(price);
    }
    else{
        AcceptableExpenseTotals[vendorDate] = parseFloat(price);
    }
}
```

This would require reformatting the output - e.g.

```
for (const [vendorDate, price] of Object.entries(AcceptableExpenses)) {
    console.log(vendorDate, price);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know the checkmark and point should be enough thanks but I wanted to preface this note with thanks before I bring up the smallest of notes: I looked up vender and vendor because while I am a terrible speller it was not actually my spelling... So it turns out there are 2 words, vender and vendor. From what I gather vender is retail and vendor is manufacture supply so in this case vender was probably the correct choice.

Answer (score 1):

1) I would like to add that the solution is not using object-oriented.
Which would add alot to the readability and extensibility of the code.
I think practically its a better as a solution then "free style - incremental programming".

The main object can be for example:
- ExpensesSheet or ExpensesCalculator
- You can pass proper formatted input object into it
- You can set up filters
- You can execute the query

2) You should consider translating long statements into functions that can be read as English

3) ExceptableCategories can be a map instead of an array to lookup isCategoryAcceptable in O(1)

4) var is old and considered bad way to define variables - js linters will recommend using const or let

i.e.: Here's a translation of your code to object-oriented style.

Note: To hide the private functions from the class interface I buried them as functions inside functions, that is not a style recommendation, just a solution I picked on the way.

```
class ExpensesCalculator {
  constructor(categories, expenses) {
    this.expensibleCateogries = new Map();
    this.expensibleExpenses = {};

    initExpensibleCategories(this, categories);
    initExpensibleExpenses(this, expenses);
    calculateTotal(this);

    function initExpensibleCategories(_this, categories) {
      categories.split('\n').forEach(category => {
        const [categoryID, categoryName, isExpensable] = category.split(',');

        if(isExpensable) {
          _this.expensibleCateogries.set(categoryID, categoryName);
        }
      })
    }

    function initExpensibleExpenses(_this, expenses) {
      expenses.split('\n').forEach(expense => {
        const [vendor, date, item, price, category] = expense.split(',');
        if (_this.expensibleCateogries.has(category)) {
          if(!_this.expensibleExpenses[date]) {
            _this.expensibleExpenses[date] = {};
          }
          if(!_this.expensibleExpenses[date][vendor]) {
            _this.expensibleExpenses[date][vendor] = 0;
          }

          _this.expensibleExpenses[date][vendor] += parseFloat(price);
        }
      })
    }

    function calculateTotal(_this) {
      _this.result = [];
      Object.keys(_this.expensibleExpenses).forEach(ddate => {
        Object.keys(_this.expensibleExpenses[ddate]).forEach(vendor=>{
          _this.result.push({
            date: new Date(ddate), 
            vendor, 
            total: _this.expensibleExpenses[ddate][vendor]})
        })
      })
    }
  }

  printReport() {
    this.result
      .sort(byDateAndVedor)
      .forEach(item=>{
        console.log(`${getFormattedDate(item.date)}: ${item.vendor} - ${item.total}`);
      })

    function byDateAndVedor(a,b) {
      return a.date - b.date === 0 ? // if date is same
      ('' + a.vendor).localeCompare(b.vendor) : // then sort by vendor
      a.date - b.date // otherwise soft by date
    }

    function getFormattedDate(date) {
      const dateTimeFormat = 
          new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' });

        const [{ value: month },,{ value: day },,{ value: year }] = dateTimeFormat.formatToParts(date);

        return `${month}/${day}/${year}`;
    }
  }
}

// Input Values
const categories = "CFE,Coffee,Y\nFD,Food,Y\nPRS,Personal,N";
const expenses = "Starbucks,3/10/2018,Iced Americano,4.28,CFE\nStarbucks,3/10/2018,Nitro Cold Brew,3.17,CFE\nStarbucks,3/10/2018,Souvineer Mug,8.19,PRS\nStarbucks,3/11/2018,Nitro Cold Brew,3.17,CFE\nHigh Point Market,3/11/2018,Iced Americano,2.75,CFE\nHigh Point Market,3/11/2018,Pastry,2.00,FD\nHigh Point Market,3/11/2018,Gift Card,10.00,PRS";

const expensesCalculator = new ExpensesCalculator(categories, expenses);
expensesCalculator.printReport();
```